# Show that the quadratic integer ring $\mathcal{O}=\{a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}|a, b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is an Euclidean Domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-algorithm, euclidean-domain

**The Problem**: Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ be a quadratic field with associated integer ring $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}[\omega]=\{a+b\omega\mid a, b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ where $\omega=\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, and field norm $N(x+y\sqrt{-3})=x^2+3y^2$ ($x, y\in\mathbb{Q}$). Show that $\mathcal{O}$ is a Euclidean Domain.

[Hint: Prove that every element of $F$ differs from an element in $\mathcal{O}$ by an element whose norm is at most $(1+|D|^2)/(16|D|)$, which is less than $1$ for the value of $-3$].

**Source**: *Abstract Algebra $\mathit{3^{rd}}$ edition* by Dummit and Foote.

**My Attempt**: I failed to make use of the hint, so I tried the following:

Suppose $\alpha, \beta\in\mathcal{O}$ and $\beta\neq0$. Suppose $\alpha=a+b\omega$ and $\beta=c+d\omega$, where $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=r+s\omega$ for some $r, s\in\mathbb{Q}$. Choose $p, q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $|r-p|, |s-q|\leq\frac{1}{2}$. Let $\theta=(r-p)+(s-q)\omega$, then let $\gamma=\beta\theta$. Then  $\gamma\in\mathcal{O}$ and $\alpha=(p+q\omega)\beta+\gamma$. Note $N(\theta)=(r-p)^2+3(s-q)^2\leq\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}=1$; so $N(\gamma)=N(\theta)N(\beta)\mathbb{\leq} N(\beta)$. **Screeching Halt**.

Obviously my approach failed because the last inequality is not strict, as required by the definition of Euclidean Domain. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{\alpha\overline\beta}{N(\beta)}$ and thus reduce it to the case of integer division.

Comment: What is $D$ in the hint?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $D=-3$ in this case-the original problem has multiple parts with $D=-2, -7, -11$, etc.

Comment: Using the hint, the norm in a complex quadratic ring is the square of the distance to $0,$ and the lattice of integer elements when $D=-3$ consists of equilateral triangles of algebraic integers - so every element in the plane is in some equilateral triangle of integer values, like $0,1,1+\omega.$ Of the points inside this triangle, the furthest point from the corners is $\frac{2+\omega}3=\frac{3+\sqrt{-3}}{6},$ the center of the triangle, which has norm $\frac{ 12}{36}=\frac{1}{3}.$ Making this rigorous is maybe a bit of work, though.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I appreciate the pointer! I am working on your first hint right now-it looks a bit more direct.

Comment: I don't get it: stick with the norm of $a+b \omega$  being $a^2 +ab+b^2$   Then the norm of $\theta=(r-p)+(s-q)\omega$  is at most $\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: @WillJagy Gosh you are absolutely correct. What was I thinking...

Answer (score 3):

In *Dummit and Foote,* the case when $D=-3$ is a subcase of $D=-3,-7,-11.$ The following proof is supposed to work for all these values of $D.$

Let $D=-3,-7,-11.$ Then $D\equiv 1\pmod 4,$ so the ring of integers of the quadratic field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ is $\Bbb{Z}\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right].$ Let $\alpha = a+b {1+\sqrt{D}\over2}$ for some $a, b \in \Bbb{Z}.$ As $\alpha$ can be written as $\alpha = \left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)+\frac{b}{2}\sqrt{D},$ we see that $\Bbb{Z}\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right] \subset \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}).$

Now, take any nonzero  $\beta = c + d {1+\sqrt{D}\over2} \in \Bbb{Z} \left[{1 + \sqrt{D} \over 2}\right].$ Since $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ is a field, in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ we have
\begin{align*}
\alpha\beta^{-1} &= \frac{\left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)+\frac{b}{2}\sqrt{D}}{\left(c+\frac{d}{2}\right)+\frac{d}{2}\sqrt{D}}\\
                 &= \frac{\left(\left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)+\frac{b}{2}\sqrt{D}\right)\left(\left(c+\frac{d}{2}\right)-\frac{d}{2}\sqrt{D}\right)}{\left(c+\frac{d}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{d}{2}\sqrt{D}\right)^2}\\
                 &= r + s\sqrt{D},
\end{align*}
where $$r = \frac{2ac+bc+ad+2bd\frac{1-D}{4}}{2\left(c^2 + cd + d^2 \frac{1-D}{4}\right)} \text{ and } s = \frac{bc-ad}{2\left(c^2+cd+\frac{1-D}{4}d^2\right)}.$$

If we can find some $\theta \in \Bbb{Z}\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right]$ such that $\alpha = \theta\beta+\gamma$ where $N(\gamma) < N(\beta),$ then we’re done. Suppose there is such an element $\theta.$ Write $\theta = u+v\sqrt{D} \in \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}).$ Then
$$\gamma = \alpha - \theta\beta = \left(\alpha\beta^{-1}-\theta\right) \beta.$$
Since the norm $N$ is multiplicative,
$$N(\gamma)=N\left(\alpha\beta^{-1}-\theta\right) N(\beta).$$
Our goal now is to show that $N\left(\alpha\beta^{-1}-\theta\right) < 1$.

Note that since $D$ is negative, $$\alpha\beta^{-1} = r+s\sqrt{D} = r+s\sqrt{|D|}i \text{ and } \theta = u+v\sqrt{D}=u+v\sqrt{|D|}i,$$ two points in the complex plane. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
N(\alpha\beta^{-1}-\theta) &= N\left((r-u)+(s-v)\sqrt{|D|}i\right)\\
                           &= (r-u)^2+(s-v)^2|D|.
\end{align*}

Take any two integers $x, y \in \Bbb{Z}$. Denoting ${1+\sqrt{D}\over2}=ω$, there are elements $x+yω$, $x+(y+1)ω$,  $(x+1)+yω$,  $(x+1)+(y+1)ω$ in the ring of integers $\Bbb{Z}\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right]=\Bbb{Z}[ω]$. These elements form a “rectangle” of minimal square (with sides of minimal possible lengths $1$ and $ω$) in the plane $\Bbb{Z}[ω]$, i.e. there cannot be any “rectangular” inside it in the plane $\Bbb{Z}[ω]$. Thus, $\Bbb{Z}[ω]$ can be viewed as a *lattice* of such rectangles of minimal square. 
As before,
\begin{align*}
x + y \omega &= \left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)+\frac{y}{2}\sqrt{|D|}i,\\x+(y+1) \omega &= \left(x+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{y}{2}\sqrt{|D|}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{|D|}\right)i\\
(x+1) + y \omega &= \left(x+\frac{y}{2}+1\right)+\frac{y}{2}\sqrt{|D|}i,\\(x+1) + (y+1) \omega &= \left(x+\frac{y}{2}+1+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{y}{2}\sqrt{|D|}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{|D|}\right)i.
\end{align*}

Plotting these points in $\Bbb{C}$ produces the following parallelogram, where the measurements in the picture are calculated from the coordinates above:
[image: lattice parallelogram with measurements]

So, a rectangle of minimal square in $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a parallelogram in $\Bbb{C}.$ Hence, since we view the plane $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$ as a *lattice of minimal-square rectangles,* the complex plane can inherently be viewed as a *lattice of such parallelograms.* Note that, by construction, this lattice covering the entire $\Bbb{C}$ is comprised of the parallelograms of minimal possible square such that their vertices belong to $\Bbb{Z}[\omega].$

Then, our point $r+s\sqrt{|D|}i$ with $r,s∈\Bbb{Q}$ lies in some parallelogram in $\Bbb{C}$. Furthermore, if we connect the vertices $x+(y+1)ω$ and $(x+1)+yω$ (as in the picture above), we get that our point $r+s\sqrt{|D|}i$ lies in some *isosceles triangle* in $\Bbb{C}$ (by the way, when $D=-3$ this triangle is equilateral). Then the maximal possible distance from $r+s\sqrt{|D|}i$ to the nearest vertex (which is also a point in the plane $\Bbb{Z}[ω]$) is achieved when $r+s\sqrt{|D|}i$ is *equidistant* from all the vertices of the isosceles triangle it lies in. Let’s denote this maximal possible distance as $l$. Then, using the picture above and the Pythagorean Theorem, we can get the following relation: $\sqrt{l^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}+l=\frac{\sqrt{|D|}}{2} ⇔ \sqrt{l^2-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{|D|}}{2}-l ⇔ l^2-\frac{1}{4}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{|D|}}{2}-l\right)^2 ⇔  l^2-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{|D|}{4}-l\sqrt{|D|}+l^2   ⇔  l\sqrt{|D|}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{|D|}{4} ⇔ l\sqrt{|D|}=\frac{1+|D|}{4}  ⇔  l=\frac{1+|D|}{4\sqrt{|D|}}$ 
 Let $r+s\sqrt{|D|}i$ be located this way inside the isosceles triangle (the worst possible case). Then, if $u+v\sqrt{D}$ (see 2.) is the nearest vertex, then, as was shown in 2., the norm $N\left(\left(r+s\sqrt{|D|}i\right)-\left(u+v\sqrt{|D|}i\right)\right)=l^2=\left(\frac{1+|D|}{4\sqrt{|D|}}\right)^2=\frac{(1+|D|)^2}{16|D|}$.

If $D=-3$, then $\frac{(1+|D|)^2}{16|D|}=\frac{(1+3)^2}{16\cdot3}=\frac{16}{48}<1$

If $D=-7$, then $\frac{(1+|D|)^2}{16|D|}=\frac{(1+7)^2}{16\cdot7}=\frac{64}{112}<1$

If $D=-11$, then $\frac{(1+|D|)^2}{16|D|}=\frac{(1+11)^2}{16\cdot11}=\frac{144}{176}<1$

So, for $D=-3,-7,-11$ we have (see 2.) that $N(γ)=N\left(\left(r+s\sqrt{D}\right)-\left(u+v\sqrt{D}\right)\right)N(β)<1\cdot{N(β)}=N(β)$, i.e., $N(γ)<N(β)$. Hence we can write $α=\left(u+v\sqrt{D}\right)β+γ$ with $N(γ)<N(β)$, where $u+v\sqrt{D}=\left(p+\frac{q}{2}\right)+\frac{q}{2}\sqrt{D}=p+q{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}∈\Bbb{Z}\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right]$ (see 2.) so that $γ=α-\left(u+v\sqrt{D}\right)β∈\Bbb{Z}\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right]$. Therefore, for any $α∈\Bbb{Z}\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right]$ and any nonzero $β∈\Bbb{Z}\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right]$ there are $μ=p+q{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}∈\Bbb{Z}\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right]$ and $γ∈\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right]$ such that $α=μβ+γ$ with $N(γ)<N(β)$. 
 **Thus, $\Bbb{Z}\left[{1+\sqrt{D}\over2}\right]$ is an Euclidean Domain for $D=-3,-7,-11$**.